# Quantile Variance and Mean

Tags: variance, mean, quantiles

As I read articles related to quantile measurements of moments, I only found quantile skewness and kurtosis definitions. However, I couldn't find any quantile estimation of variance or mean. Is it possible to formulate them in the same way as quantile skewness and kurtosis were defined?

Like:

```
Bowley's Q.S. = ((Q_3 - Q_2)-(Q_2 - Q_1))/(Q_3 - Q_1)
```

Comment: As population quantities, "variance" and "mean" have precise definitions while "skewness" and "kurtosis" are less specific, there are numerous population measures for each. The general notions you probably seek are "location" and "spread" or "scale" and example quantile measures of location and spread would be the median and the interquartile range.

Comment: @Glen_b so does that mean we are unable to define quantile based mean or variance?

Comment: Well, no, given their definitions, you can certainly obtain the sample mean as the average of all the available sample quantiles (since you just end up averaging the data either way). You could similarly obtain the sample variance by using all the quantiles and putting them into the usual variance formula. ... I expect that's not what you want -- but what you actually want is less than clear. If you don't want "mean" and "variance" to match their usual definitions you need to clarify what you intend when you use those terms.

Comment: Some good analogs of mean and standard deviation in quantile statistics are the median and interquartile range respectively -- and analogs are what people usually want in quantile statistics: things with some but not all of the properties of corresponding moment-based statistics.